# Delphi + Firebird (using DBExpress): aggregate issue with TFMTBCDField

Tags: delphi, aggregate, firebird, numeric

I have a table with a `NUMERIC(15,2)` field in my database. In Delphi, I use the trio `TSQLDataset` + `TDataSetProvider` + `TClientDataSet`. This field is created as `TFMTBCDField`. The problem is that I need to use an Aggregate field in my `ClientDataSet` in order to sum the values and for some reason it's not calculated correctly (see image below). However, if I set my field type as `DOUBLE PRECISION` in my database (Delphi creates the field as `TFloatField` in dataset) the aggregate works as expected.

PS: I've read somewhere that is better using `NUMERIC` than `DOUBLE PRECISION` in Firebird.

- I'm using Delphi XE7 and Firebird 2.5

[image: aggregate issue]

How do you deal with this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: The `TFMTBCDField` is a binary coded decimal field, Firebird doesn't use binary coded decimals, maybe that is why the addition fails.

Comment: "better using NUMERIC than DOUBLE PRECISION" - dunno what you mean. There is no "one size fits all" universal laws, there are specific situations and specific pitfalls in those situations, that are better be avoided. In this generalized form your rule sounds strange, verily so. There was inconsistency in NUMERIC handling between legacy "dialect 1" and modern "dialect 3", but that was exactly solved by explicitly using DOUBLE instead of NUMERIC... https://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/isql-dialects.html

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're right about Firebird. But NUMERIC and DECIMAL datatypes are mapped  to TFMTBCD(TFMTBCDField) from DbExpress driver in Delphi.

Comment: @ValMarinov Well, I don't actually know Delphi, so I was just guessing as to a cause.

Comment: `TClientDataSet` is not DBX, it is MIDAS aka DataSnap. Anyway, why won't you change the type of the field from BCD to some real number field class and give it another try ?

Comment: google tells many DBX (and non-DBX) drivers have EnableBCD connection parameter that may be set to False.... Dunno if it would apply to Delphi out-of-the-box firebird DBX driver. Also there are alternative DBX drivers for Firebird, such as DevArt's driver and free (but closed sourced) Chinese driver.

Comment: Frankly, in Dialect 3 the `Numeric(15,?)` is 64-bit integer, so perhaps `TFmtBCD` is better choice than `TFloatField` with regard to accuracy and formatting. Then it is a question to MIDAS (which sometimes seems to be overly complex and little maintained) why it fails to sum it up. Perhaps you have to somehow prohibit BCD and go with float fields instead. http://www.ibase.ru/round/ http://www.ibase.ru/ibp_60_exact_num_fs/ http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/XE7/en/DECIMAL_and_NUMERIC_Data_Types